# tor friendly reverse proxy to share same public port for onion/nonion websites?

Tags: website, server, web-proxy

i m looking for a solution to announce a website on both clear/dark nets using same ip, same public port.

Reading various documentation i m not so sure this is ever possible.

Do you have some ideas ? links i might have missed. or maybe ready to use software if i m wrong.

thanks

*edit: maybe i could use ipv4 for clear net and ipv6 for tor ? i think i have those two on the server.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you consider to be the “dark net”? Is your website supposed to be anonymous?

Comment: your question is not related to the problem i ask. and no i m not about to link this pseudo with this website sorry. my goal is only to bring people that might need tor for real some day to have try once about it ahead of time. or at least demonstrate its not all about drugs.;.... anyways. i guess i ll do by myself as usual. i dont really like your attitude.

Comment: I’m not really sure what you’re trying to say. If you could reword your question so that we can understand it, we can try to help.